# Is it possible to let onEdit trigger for fontstylechanges? (line-through)

Tags: google-apps-script, triggers, google-sheets

Got here two scripts that change the font color based on line-through, both are working.
- First one can be custom triggered,
- Second is onEdit.

The onEdit has my preference, as it automates things instantly, however onEdit does not see changes when a cell's value is getting line-through yes or no.

So is it possible to let onEdit trigger for fontstylechanges?

```
function colorlinethrough() {
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet(); // Get spreadsheet
    var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0]; // Get first Sheet
    var range = sheet.getDataRange(); // Get cells
    var data = range.getValues(); // Get the cell values

    for (var i in data) {
    var editrange = sheet.getRange(parseInt(i)+1,2);
        if (editrange.getFontLine() == "line-through") {
            editrange.setFontColor("#CCCCCC");
        }
        else {
            editrange.setFontColor("#000000");
        }
    }
};

function onEdit(e) {
    var ss = e.source; // Get spreadsheet
    var range = ss.getActiveRange();
    if (range.getFontLine() == "line-through") {
        range.setFontColor("#CCCCCC");
    }
    else {
        range.setFontColor("#000000");
    }
};
```

also put this question on the g+ community https://plus.google.com/104787958270362345970/posts/GTdBoTZR3YF

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Spreadsheets has an `onChange` event that might do the trick here. `onEdit` is when the data changes and `onChange` is when the spreadsheet UI itself changes. Give it a shot.

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/understanding_events

Comment: Will surely do! thanks for the suggestion, will try it out tonight and report back!

Comment: Alright, onChange does indeed do the job! However it only works with the colorlinethrough() function and not with the onEdit(e) function (which I changed by name). I think the onEdit(e) function would be more efficient if onChange could work with it as it only looks at the changed cell range.. is this because on change does not give a range object?

Comment: Btw handy to know that there is a gui for editing and creating triggers, did not know that, so i was initially messing with changing the function names XD!

Comment: Good to know. Yes, the range is not functional today with onChange triggers. See and track this issue - https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=3269